# Have a pop up window when clicking on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, window, edit

Sometime in websites you see that when you click on an edit image, a pop up window appears. In this pop up window, there may be for example, a check box list, or you can attach a file,... and then there is and OK or Return button. 
How can I implement this kind of window? Should I use JavaScript? Also do you know any website for tutorial?

Comment: Google "javascript modal", "javascript popup", "javascript dialog", "javascript confirm", etc and you will find lots of goodies.

Comment: Why did you waste your time making an account on here and not just type the exact same thing into google...

Comment: [https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: I did, but I could not find what I was looking for. That is why I have posted a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing dialogs / popups in the past, I have used jquery dialogs. You can find documentation here for jquery dialogs: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/.